# Using CSS in JSF

Tags: css, jsf

I have a JSF facelet that has a String of text that I would like to style using CSS. It is in an h1 tag:

```
<h1 align="center">Welcome Back</h1>
```

My questions are, first, where in the directory structure of the JSF app would the CSS file go, and 2nd, how would I add the CSS styling to the text?

Thanks!

Comment: The `align` attribute isn't supported by HTML5. Use a stylesheet and use `text-align: center;`.

Answer (score 2):

> *I have a JSF facelet that has a String of text that I would like to style using CSS. It is in an h1 tag:*
> `<h1 align="center">Welcome Back</h1>`

That's a good idea. The `align` attribute is [invalid](http://validator.w3.org) HTML5. CSS goes in the `style` attribute, or better, in its own `.css` file. You should strive to keep your JSF/HTML code free of `style` attributes (and thus *all* the styling goes in `.css` file).

---

> *My questions are, first, where in the directory structure of the JSF app would the CSS file go*

All JSF resources should go in the `/resources` folder (if necessary divided further in subfolders). Here's a rather basic example:

```
WebContent
 |-- META-INF
 |-- WEB-INF
 |    |-- template.xhtml
 |    |-- faces-config.xml
 |    `-- web.xml
 |-- resources
 |    |-- image.png
 |    |-- script.js
 |    `-- style.css
 `-- index.xhtml
```

You need to reference it as follows in the `<h:head>` of the master template.

```
<h:outputStylesheet name="style.css" />
```

*(equivalently there are `<h:outputScript>` and `<h:graphicImage>` for JS and images)*

---

> *and 2nd, how would I add the CSS styling to the text?*

Just by the following entry in `style.css`, provided that your website is designed in such way that it has *only one* `<h1>` in the master layout template which is the same throughout the site.

```css
h1 {
    text-align: center;
}
```

Otherwise you'd need to give it an `id` or `class` instead. When writing CSS for JSF, please keep in mind that CSS works on JSF-generated HTML output in the client side only, not on JSF source code in the server side. So, when in doubt about the HTML output, open the JSF page in webbrowser and do *View Source* (or a tree inspection with webbrowser's developer toolset).

#### See also:

- [HTML Dog - CSS Beginner Tutorial](http://www.htmldog.com/guides/cssbeginner/)
- [What is the JSF resource library for and how should it be used?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11988415/what-is-the-jsf-resource-library-for-and-how-should-it-be-used)